# Creating a new variable just for use in a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose we have the following piece of Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = null;

    try {
        map = readFromFile(); //Method that reads from file, throws IOException
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //do something
    }

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.stream().map(x -> map.get(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above code would not compile, because `map` is not final or effectively final. However, when we replace `map` by some other variable, the code does compile. The last two lines of code could look like the following in after the replacement.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapReplacement = map;
list.stream().map(x -> mapReplacement.get(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It seems odd to me that it is necessary to assign the same map to another variable just to be able to use it in a stream. Is there any other (perhaps better) way of handling this? It would work if the `map` variable would only be assigned to once, but to accomplish that one would have to wrap the whole piece of code in a try-block, which doesn't seem like the way to go to me.

Comment: What's the question? This is an observation. EDIT: Sorry, I see it now.

Comment: The question is in the last paragraph: "Is there any other (perhaps better) way of handling this?" EDIT: That's no problem.

Comment: Just a note: you could get a NPE if you don't put those 2 lines in the try block.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is that your map field (the pointer) resides on the stack  i.e. in your methods stack frame. When you use the lambda expression as you are here there is a chance that you will take that value and store it away somewhere. If you did this and then your method ended that pointer would be to an invalid location (Your stack frame would be gone). When you make your reference final or in this case effectively final you are allow the compiler to make a copy of the reference to the location in the heap instead a pointer to your field in the stack frame.

Comment: If you do _not_ initialize `map` to null, what happens?  (I conjecture that it might become effectively final.)

Comment: @ChuckLowery Thank you for the explanation. That helps me understand why I have to create a new (final or effectively final) variable. Are you saying that, because of this, there is no better way to handle this situation?

Comment: @LouisWasserman That results in a compiler error, because `map` may not have been initialized.

Comment: Eh, you could do that.  Or you could move everything inside the `try` block, including the declaration of `map`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It would work if I move everything inside the try block, but I was specifically wondering how to handle this case (where the declaration is outside and the assignment inside the `try`-block).

Comment: @SharpKnight 
1. you could make your `readFromFile` method throw a specific runtime exception which would remove the need for the try block. 
2. You could move all your logic into your try as  @LouisWasserman has stated.

Why would you attempt to execute the last line if the try failed? In other words why are you attempting to perform this operation outside the try?

Comment: The root issue here, in my opinion, is that the main() method does 2 different things. I'd split it's content to 2 methods, something like: initMap and processMap. The first reads the file, handles the exception and returns a final map, and the second uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is surprisingly in the code you have not shown - your comment line :)

```
catch (IOException e) {
    //do something
}
```

**What exactly** will you do in case of your `readFromFile()` method *does* throw the exception?

### 1. Continue processing

Will you continue the processing with an empty map? So your `readFromFile()` should then *return an empty map* and not throw the exception. (Or you may wrap the method into another one.)

```
public static void test1(String[] args) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = readFromFile();
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream().map(x -> map.get(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

### 2. Stop processing

Will you stop the further processing? Then simply *return* from the method. (Of course you should not just swallow the exception but to let the client method somehow know.)

```
public static void test1(String[] args) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map;

    try {
        map = readFromFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle the exceptional situation
        return; // or throw another exception, but leave the method
    }

    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.stream().map(x -> map.get(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

ADDED:

If you want your `readFromFile()` method to throw an exception, think about wrapping the original exception into some your own exception. Of course it depends on where the method is in your application logic. If you consider it as a low-level method, `IOException` quite suits the purpose. If you consider it more high-level, you should create your own exception reflecting the business logic of the method.

In *both* the cases do not forget to proper handle CLOSING of the input file in your `readFromFile()` method, especially in the case of exception. You may use the Java 7 [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature.

Comment: +1 You saved me the trouble of writing something similar. :-) An additional point relative to #1 is that `readFromFile()` **already** must catch IOException since it opens and reads the file and must close it reliably. If it gets an exception, it has already detected this case and is thus in a position to return something sensible to the caller, such as an empty Map.

Comment: @StuartMarks: I also understand that `readFromFile()` must already have catched the IOException, but I supposed that it re-throws it (or even just pass upwards). You are right with reminding the proper close. I will edit my response accordingly. Thanks.